# two sum метод двух указателей

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Решаю задачку две суммы с литкода: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/ (найти пару целых чисел в массиве которая в сумме равна заданному числу; вывести индексы этих пар)
На [3, 2, 4] валиться если решаю так:

```
nums.sort()

left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1
while left < right:
    summa = nums[left] + nums[right]

    if summa == target:
        return left, right
    elif target > summa:
        left += 1
    elif target < summa:
        right -= 1
```

Понятно почему - мы переставили индексы. Но во всех других случаях работает. Везде говорится, что методом двух указателей эта задача 100% решается. Как решить именно этим методом и почему так

Comment: что произойдёт при отсутствии решения? => [10,20,30] 15

Comment: Текст задачи должен быть прямо в вопросе и на русском языке.

Comment: @ganz leetcode You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution

Comment: @headswillroll "no answer" it is just one solution

Comment: @ganz я к тому, что там в условии прописано отсутствие такого случая, хотя и не составляет труда написать return None, None в конце

Comment: @headswillroll в конце чего? файла или цикла, который зависнет при невозможности найти решение?

Comment: @ganz хватит душнить, ты понял, про что я говорю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод двух указателей работает для **сортированного** массива.  Собственно, `nums.sort()` вы для этого и используете, но индексы не сохраняете.

Используйте два цикла (медленно), хэш-таблицу (быстро, но память требуется, при размере задачи 10^4 это не проблема), или, если требуется именно метод двух указателей - сортируйте **вместе с индексами** (параллельный массив или сделать список пар значение-индекс (кортежей или списков))

```
    ns = [(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(nums)]
    ns.sort()

    left, right = 0, len(ns) - 1
    while left < right:
        summa = ns[left][0] + ns[right][0]

        if summa == target:
            return ns[left][1], ns[right][1]
        elif target > summa:
            left += 1
        elif target < summa:
            right -= 1
```